# Example of simple modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, localization

> Find a simple $\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$-module.

What would be an example and how would we think about this type of problems?

First I looked at the $\mathbb{Z}$-module $\mathbb{Z}/p$ localized at the multiplicative set $S=\{1,2,2^2, 2^3,\cdots\}$ which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[1/2] \otimes \mathbb{Z}/p$ as a $\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$-module, but I am not sure what the submodule of a tensor product would look like...

Thank you.

Comment: Show that the simple modules over any commutative ring $R$ are all of the form $R/m$ where $m$ is a maximal ideal. Now classify the maximal ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$ (or just find one). The tensor product of $\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$ with $\mathbb{Z}/p$ is $\mathbb{Z}/p$ for $p$ odd and $0$ if $p = 2$.

Comment: Thank you Qiaochu and I added the solution below. For the tensor product of $\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$ with $\mathbb{Z}/p$ (assume $p\neq 2$) when you say the same, do you mean as $\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$-module ? For any $k/2^n$ there exists $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $ap+ b2^n = 1$ so $k/2^n \otimes 1$ is the same as $bk\otimes 1 = 1 \otimes bk$, but how should I define the map between them?

Comment: The $\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$-module structure on a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, when it exists, is unique. This is true more generally for any localization. In general an $S^{-1} R$-module is the same thing as an $R$-module in which every element of $S$ acts invertibly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow from Qiaochu's comment.

Given any non zero $m\in M$, $Rm = M$ since $M$ is simple, so we have the surjective $R$-module map 
$$f: R\rightarrow M$$
and $R/\ker(f) \cong M$ as $R$-module.

$\ker(f)$ must be a maximal ideal, or else it is contained in some other maximal ideal $I$, then we have a proper submodule of $M$
$$I/\ker(f) \subsetneq R/\ker(f) \cong M.$$

Since $\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$ is the $\mathbb{Z}$ localized at the multiplicative set $S=\{2^n: n=1,2, \cdots\}$, and there is a inclusion preserving bijection between maximal (also prime) ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$ with $I\cap S = \emptyset$ and $\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$ given by the map $I \mapsto I\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$. so $I = 3\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$ would be a maximal ideal and $R/I$ is a simple $\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$-module.